# Calling neighbours issue?

Tags: the-sims

Whenever I try to call a neighbour I almost always get yelled at and they hang up immediately.I'm not calling them late in the night.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you do something else to piss them off?

Comment: Do your neighbours dislike you? Is the yelling in the form of one of the dialogue pop-ups (like when you phone a Sim late at night) or just yelling in Simlish down the phone? If it's the latter, they probably just don't like your Sim that much.

Comment: @Topperfalkon all my relationships are high. They aren't my friends yet but I can't get them to be my firends if I can't talk to them

Comment: So is this occurring with all neighbours? If you start a new game (keep your old one, obviously) do you get the same issue? That's quite a strange issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the answer (I think). From the testing I've done you can't chat with another sim on the phone unless you know them better. To do this call them and invite them over then raise your friendship once they come over.

Seems odd but, that's the only way it seems to work for me.